# Getting more information about a PGP Signature

Tags: gnupg

I've asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170000/read-pgp-signature-using-bouncycastle but I'm hoping to be able to get more information about the format of a GnuPG signature and how to decode it.

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

iQEcBBABCAAGBQJYnkPxAAoJEBFjzYGyXBOsXRoH/3O4bwKK45aUN+m0N4jsZ+n5
W8R/aGti/llvJ62tHBCO5BIp/pp+b1Gdv99xtnJXHu/f0TqPYj+fwq4vfaorNTtA
Vtq8MaMesw1OWZEfu/lyjNOwdg81FUlYkw0Bjo3H/MxWjWYUiHmJo+OGriyf5dv/
433ZqitZMxLHCfZsuoU5teZ0BPUSoNjF6hOFK3ZI7QXsgYUyohzW2goy9bDVCKRq
e73CHpnMKCrnDc+/4+sK349bD/cZp6/c0T8b7cBCeBGGilPD6ovJUQE5vhGTKnJM
lgyxhA87tw9wqFwpZXDr0nzOP+MFfE9WRGecVYZ9G+LP/biefSe5iWRaPIcZIi0=
=qUHb
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

When I try to verify using JCA, I got an error that says:

```
'Signature length not correct: got 287 but was expecting 256'
```

I'm hoping to get some more light on how the signature is encoded and how to access the actual bytes that are used for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use gpg commandline:

```
$ gpg -vv
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

iQEcBBABCAAGBQJYnkPxAAoJEBFjzYGyXBOsXRoH/3O4bwKK45aUN+m0N4jsZ+n5
W8R/aGti/llvJ62tHBCO5BIp/pp+b1Gdv99xtnJXHu/f0TqPYj+fwq4vfaorNTtA
Vtq8MaMesw1OWZEfu/lyjNOwdg81FUlYkw0Bjo3H/MxWjWYUiHmJo+OGriyf5dv/
433ZqitZMxLHCfZsuoU5teZ0BPUSoNjF6hOFK3ZI7QXsgYUyohzW2goy9bDVCKRq
e73CHpnMKCrnDc+/4+sK349bD/cZp6/c0T8b7cBCeBGGilPD6ovJUQE5vhGTKnJM
lgyxhA87tw9wqFwpZXDr0nzOP+MFfE9WRGecVYZ9G+LP/biefSe5iWRaPIcZIi0=
=qUHb
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE
gpg: armor header: Version: GnuPG v2
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 1163CD81B25C13AC
    version 4, created 1486767089, md5len 0, sigclass 0x10
    digest algo 8, begin of digest 5d 1a
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2017-02-10)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 1163CD81B25C13AC)
    data: [2047 bits]
```

As you can see, the signature can be decoded. Without the signed data however I can´t give you more information, specifically if the signature is valid. I do not find the issuer/signer on https://pgp.mit.edu/

Try to paste the whole message including signature into gpg -vv and see if it gives you more information.